# Is there anything like an execute_if algorithm in stl?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Just as there are count_if and remove_if algorithms in STL, I'd like to find something like an execute_if, that would take the condition predicate separately from the function to execute.

For example I would like 1 line that prints all the odds using 2 lambdas, something like this:

```
auto vec = vector<int>{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
for_each_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](auto val) {return val % 2 != 0; }, [](auto val) { cout << val; });
```

What's a good way to do this with algorithms?

Comment: Why would such an algorithm exist today? The functor can literally do *anything*, and with lambdas we can compose existing functors easily.

Comment: `std::for_each` and lambda which contains an `if`? It is much clearer than your proposal.

Comment: How would an `execute_if` function differ from a normal `if` statement?

Comment: separation of concerns. For example: One caller would send ifodds, another caller would send ifevens. Both would send a printer. Or one caller sends a numberprinter, antoher sends a something else. Both would send ifodds.

Comment: Why do you need two lambdas?   Since C++11, `std::copy_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator(std::cout, " "), [](auto val) {return val %2 != 0;})` will do what you seek  (assuming you want spaces between the output values).

Answer (score 5):

If you have C++20 support, you can make use of the new [range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges)-library:

```
std::vector<int> vec{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
for (auto val : vec | std::views::filter([](auto val) { return val % 2 != 0; }))
{
    std::cout << val;
}
```

Or (of course):

```
std::vector<int> vec{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
auto filtered = vec | std::views::filter([](auto val) {return val % 2 != 0; });
std::for_each(filtered.begin(), filtered.end(), [](auto val) { std::cout << val; } );
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/P84qoP)

Answer (score 4):

You could write such an algorithm yourself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>


template <typename IT,typename predicate,typename func>
void for_each_if(IT begin,IT end,predicate p, func f){
    std::for_each(begin,end,[&f,&p](auto val){
        if (p(val)) f(val);
    });
}


int main() {
    auto vec = std::vector<int>{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
    for_each_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](auto val) {return val % 2 != 0; }, [](auto val) { std::cout << val; });
}
```

However, be prepared for a debatte on which one is actually more readable. I definitely prefer to pass only one functor to `for_each` instead of passing two functors to `for_each_if`.

> separation of concerns. One caller would send ifodds, another caller would send ifevens. Both would send a printer.

You don't need an extra algorithm for that. The alternative to the above is:

```
auto condition = [](auto val) {return val % 2 != 0; };
auto func = [](auto val) { std::cout << val; };
auto if_fun = [&condition,&func](auto val){ if (condition(val)) func(val);};
std::for_each(vec.begin(),vec.end(),if_fun);
```

You can compose `if_fun` from different predicates and different functions as you wish.

Comment: It is a matter of convenience and clarity. By your logic then, we don't need count_if. I can just do a foreach and count the matches myself.

Comment: @GonenI the  reason to use standard algorithms is readability and expressiveness, but that advantage stems mainly from the fact that they are standard. You can invent the nicest algorithm that you consider as super readable, but it is difficult to compete with standard algorithms that everybody knows, documentation is everywhere and they are tested and debugged by millions of users

Comment: @GonenI anyhow I didnt mean to imply this "By your logic then, we don't need count_if." If you read this in the answer then perhaps I didn't  explain myself well enough